# Advent Of Code 2020 Day 3: Answer always 1 less than expected

Tags: arrays, c, file, parsing

I'm currently working through day 3 of advent of code 2020 and I've been stuck on question 3 where my answer creates an output ALWAYS 1 lower than expected. For example to the example my program outputs 6 while it was supposed to output 7, for the input i've received i've got 177 while the answer was 178.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_tree_found(char* line, int position, int line_size)
{
    return line[position % (line_size - 1)] == '#';
}

int main(void) 
{
    FILE* file;
    size_t file_size = 0;
    int line_size = 0;
    char* raw_line = NULL;
    int trees = 0;
    int pos_x = 0;

    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    while ((line_size = getline(&raw_line, &file_size, file)) != -1)
    {
        if (is_tree_found(raw_line, pos_x, line_size)) trees++;

        pos_x += 3;
    }

    printf("Trees: %i", trees);
}
```

And here is the question along with my input.txt file.

Question: https://pastebin.com/fZ1SG5xm
Input: https://pastebin.com/3CHNyHfP

Comment: Your code works for me. Perhaps your error is related to the assumption that every line is terminated with a newline character. If the last line is not correctly terminated, then your modulo computation will be incorrect.

Comment: @rici what do you mean correctly terminated?

Comment: @cepb: I mean that the line terminates with a newline character as per Posix base definitions 3.206. As I'm sure you know, the C standard says that whether a text file is required to end with a newline is implementation-defined; on a Posix implementation, it is required.

Comment: Add one to the result: problem solved.

Comment: @rici, but as a programmer you have to think of any scenario. You cannot assume that file will be per POSIX standard.

Comment: @cepb: exactly. You shouldn't make the assumption that the file is a valid text file. That's why I pointed it out in my comment. Your question had to do with my terminology, which is orthogonal. But antti wrote the answer, which is cool.

Comment: Anyway, competitive programs like this rarely if ever consider bad inputs. For example, the program would also fail if the lines had inconsistent length, for example because of trailing white space. And it wouldn't notice an invalid character. That's one of the reasons programming competitions aren't good for learning how to write programs (imho). But they can still be fun.

Answer (score 0):

As Rici noticed, it seems that the problem is that you're perhaps using a broken text editor to save the `input.txt` and the last line is thus not properly terminated. My input works, but if I manually remove the last line <s>separator</s> terminator, I get wrong number.

You can use `strcspn` to count number of characters until newline:

```
int actual_line_size = strcspn(raw_line, "\n");
if (is_tree_found(raw_line, pos_x, actual_line_size)) ...
```

(Alternatively you can scan backwards from `line_size` until you find a character that is not `'\n'`, but this technique works for even `fgets`).

Remember to remove adjustment for line size too:

```
return line[position % line_size] == '#';
```

---

P.S. since in this case the input is a 2D grid, it should be sufficient that you calculate the width only once:

```
int grid_width = -1;

while (...) {
    ...
    if (grid_width == -1) {
        grid_width = strcspn(line, "\n");
    }
    if (is_tree_found(raw_line, pos_x, grid_width)) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Text editors, are not broken if they do not terminate last line with EOL symbol, one example is vim which will by default do it, but you can turn it off w `set noeol` command. Quite useful when you edit binary files :)

Comment: With getline, you don't need to scan. You can just check `if (raw_line[line_size-1] == '\n') --line_size;`. That's one of its big advantages over `fgets`; it tells you exactly how many characters it read.

Comment: @CEPB according to POSIX a line in a text file must be terminated with `\n`. Note that this is specifically a case of *the inputs* on Advent of Code are properly terminated with `\n` and perhaps OP copy pasting the input into a text editor to save it into another file and *that* process lost the line terminator.

Comment: I insist, with getline there is no need to scan, forwards or backwards. Getline stops reading the first time it encounters a newline, or at the end of the input stream whichever happens first. So there is at most one newline character, and if there is one it's the last character.

Comment: @rici then you need to write another answer :P I need to write some documentation now :sigh: